# Условия в SCSS: отображение псевдоэлемента в зависимости от высоты родителя

Tags: css, scss

Можно ли отображать псевдоэлемент только в том случае, когда высота родителя больше определенного значения, используя только директиву @if из SCSS, не добавляя дополнительных классов при помощи JS?

Пример: когда высота родителя - 1 строка текста - псевдоэлемента нет http://prntscr.com/nv8th1

Когда высота родителя становится выше, чем одна строка текста, появляется псевдоэлемент http://prntscr.com/nv8tmj

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего @if вам не поможет, т.к. sass компилится в css, а css не умеет управлять условиями.

Мое решение - идея. Не идеально, работает при определенных условиях, но вдруг поможет.

У контейнера - 2 псевдоэлемента. Один - стрелка, другой - перекрытие цвета фона.

Когда у нас одна строка - стрелка перекрыта вторым псевдоэлементом. Когда больше одной строки - открыта.

```
<div class="pane">Одна строка</div>
<div class="pane">Две <br/>строки</div>
```

```
.pane {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;;
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
 }

 .pane:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 7px;
   right: 0;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   margin: 0 -10px 0 0;
   border-top: 7px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
   border-left: 10px solid #999;
}

.pane:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7px;
  right: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: -10px -10px 0 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/2wutxkvf/8/

Comment: Это работает, когда стрелка сверху, а когда посередине - нет(